# NavigateUrl="#" becomes href="SubFolder/#"?

Tags: asp.net

This isn't exactly Fermat's last theorem, but it keeps coming back to annoy me like an unpaid phone bill from college. Sometimes I want to create a `HyperLink` that does not cause a postback, so I want the target url to be #. When the markup happens to be from a UserControl in a subfolder,

```
/
|- Home.aspx (uses UC.ascx)
|- Sub
   |- UC.ascx
```

the URL is rewritten with a relative path, e.g.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" >Click Me!</asp:HyperLink>
```

becomes

```
<a href="SubFolder/#">Click Me!</a>
```

Which is, unfortunately, wrong. Obviously I can get around this by not using a server control, but it seems stupid. Can this be avoided?

The point here is I will add a click event with jQuery or in code-behind, and I never want it to cause a postback, but I want it to be a hyperlink for CSS reasons.

Comment: You can cancel the navigation using the event object. function(e){ e.preventDefault(); } . If you are going to use jQuery to bind some event there is no point in using a server control.

Comment: In this particular case logic on the server controls visibility of the link as well as the specific code of the javascript event. There are ways around this of course (e.g. I just wrap it in a placeholder, and use <% %> markup to define the click event in the markup) but it seems silly that I would have to do one of these things (use javascript to prevent navigation, and/or not use a server control) to do something so basic that could be done much more elegantly with a server control that worked right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

easy way:

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" 
                navigateUrl="#" 
                onclick="javascript:return false;"                   
                runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

or

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" 
                href="#" 
                runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

or jquery add a class to the link you don't want to have a postback (nopostback) :

```
$("a.nopostback").bind('click', function () {
     return false;
})
```

Comment: The second option works. The first doesn't work. The last he state that doesn't really suits his case.

Comment: #2 is the answer... which, in retrospect, seems so obvious! Thanks! Just for the record, `NavigateUrl="./#"` still renders as `href="SubFolder/#"`

Comment: edited, first answer made no sense, was a small remnant of an experiment, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Are you saying that the lowercase "navigateURL" will render as "href" without rewriting the url? Why wouldn't that just render as "navigateUrl"?

Comment: Huh, I'm surprised #2 works, as href is not a property on the [Hyperlink class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx). I suppose ASP.NET automatically places properties it doesn't recognize on web controls on the emitted HTML.

Comment: @BrunoLM, I was wondering, if he was modifing the attributes on server side, he could as well modify the className... but anyway, I guess I went beyond the question with that indeed ;)

Comment: @adamjford yes, you can add any attributes you want that way to server controls. I never thought of trying it though, because I assumed asp.net would overwrite or ignore it, since it's an automatically generated attribute (from NavigateUrl)

Comment: I knew that I could add attributes to server-side controls. I got so much obsessed for the lack of the option to suppress the resolveUrl that I completely forgot about it :P Nice catch Caspar

Answer (score 6):

You can set attributes for server-side elements.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Click me"
    href="#" style="color: red;" />
```

In the code-behind as well, using `Attributes` property

```
HyperLink1.Attributes
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, adding the control to the page **without** the href/NavigateUrl attribute(s) offers the greatest flexiblity.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"/>
```

Then assigning the href attribute in your code behind looks like Bruno's answer:

```
HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("href","{your-value-here}");
```

Though, Bruno and Caspar's answers work they break in certain contexts. For example, say your HyperLink control is nested in a Repeater. If you then wanted to conditionally set the href attribute to an actual URL or '#' those approaches will not work. The '#' will be rendered every time.